# Element is not removed from html by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code and its not working

```
var data = '<div class="myform" id="stylized"><form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" id="form1"><h1>Account form</h1></form></div>';

$(data).find('h1').remove();
alert(data);
```

here h1 is still there in result

Comment: is the code inside the jquery $.ready?

Comment: What about finding? can you find the h1 tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking a string and building a DOM structure from it (that's what `$(data)` does).  You're then modifying that DOM structure (with the `remove`) call.  That change affects the DOM structure. *It does not affect the original string.*

If you want the string back out again, you'll have to retrieve it.

```
$data = $(data);
$data.find('h1').remove();
data = $data.html();
```

Comment: we need to `.end()` the chain in order to get the parent nodes again. Otherwise we'd output the html from the removed node.

Comment: @lone i am only getting  from the <form tag , the parent DIV tag is still missing , same problem as j Andy

Comment: @user824981 You want the outer HTML concept then. This is possible, but it isn't easy for the very simple reason that it's very rarely necessary. What are you going to do with the value you get?

Comment: @lone This is the code of html form which i get via ajax request. i am loading the form in jquery dialog box. but i want to extract the title from h1 tag and put as title of dialog box and then remove the title from html and then display in body of dialog box

Comment: @user Then you don't need the HTML.  You can just append the jQuery selection to the dialog box.

Comment: this is the code where i put data   `$('#dialog-confirm').html(data).dialog('open');` , so how can i append it

Comment: @user Using `$data` from above, `$('#dialog-confirm').html($data).dialog('open')`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're just updating the `jQuery wrapped set`, not the `data variable`. You need to assign the new formed jQuery set and access it's `.html()` method to get the result:

```
var data = '<div class="myform" id="stylized"><form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" id="form1"><h1>Account form</h1></form></div>';

var $myData = $(data).find('h1').remove().end();
alert($myData.html());
```

Comment: i am only getting now from the <form tag , the parent DIV tag is still missing chk here http://jsfiddle.net/QNnLe/5/